# How can I change the name of pdf?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf

I want to change the name of pdf from `"Name_Exemple.pdf"` to `"FAB_Name_Exemple.pdf"`. Is there any way to do it?

```
PDF::Output($modal->title.'.pdf','D');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PDF::Output('FAB_' . $modal->title.'.pdf','D');
// update
PDF::Output('FAB ' . str_replace('_', ' ', $modal->title) . '.pdf','D');
```

Comment: thank you so much!! Another question: can I made it to be "Fab Name Exemple.pdf"? Without _ ?